# blank pdf attachment sent using FPDF and SwiftMailer

Tags: php, pdf, swiftmailer

I am trying to create a PDF stream using FPDF library and to send the pdf over e-mail using Swift Mailer. Below is my code. The mail is sent successfully and even pdf is also attached but the pdf is blank. It has a size of 1Kb and can be opened as a pdf.

My code is :

```
<?php

include('./fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once './lib/swift_required.php';
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Text(40, 10, "Dummy text");
$data=$pdf->Output('./emails/order.pdf', 'F');
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
    ->setFrom(array("admin@mysite.com" => 'Company Admin'))
    ->setTo('my@email.com')
    ->setBody('This is body text', 'text/html');    
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath('./emails/order.pdf');
//$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($data, 'pdf_name.pdf', 'application/pdf');
  $message->attach($attachment);
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

I referred to this question [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369012/blank-pdf-attachment-while-sent-using-fpdf-and-swiftmailer)

Comment: break it down, is it a mailer of pdf creation issue?

Comment: @dagon Well switmailer seems to be sending the email ok, so I guess it is an fpdf issue

Comment: I finally got it to work. I changed the code as follows: `$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);` as edited above and it worked. I think the problem was in in the AddPage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I changed the code as follows:

`$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);`

as edited above and it worked. I think the problem was in in the AddPage.